# Django ModelForm's insertion form also shows existing records

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am using ModelForms to generate some user registry data. When I submit the form, the record is indeed added. However, the existing records also show up in form format. I just want to add new users.

Sign up html form:

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Sign up</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/users/signup/">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{ formset }}     
                <tr><th><input type="submit" /></th></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Function that declares the ModelForms:

```
def model_signup(request):
    ModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Model)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ModelFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = ModelFormSet()
    return render_to_response("model_signup.html", {
        "formset": formset,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [specify a queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) when creating a formset. If you don't want to show existing records, use the empty queryset `MyModel.objects.none()`.

```
ModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = ModelFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=MyModel.objects.none())
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        # do something.
else:
    formset = ModelFormSet(queryset=MyModel.objects.none())
```